# sas generated blob url sends bad request 400 to azure ocr api

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I have uploaded some images to azure blob container for my azure ocr api to read the image and send back the output.

I have retrieved list of blobs from azure container using

```
 blob_service.list_blobs().
```

Each of these retrieved blobs are now given to shared access method

```
generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name='ocr-images',blob_name=blob.name,permission=PublicAccess.OFF,expiry='se=2015-04-30T02%3A23%3A26Z',start='st=2015-04-29T22%3A18%3A26Z')
```

output of shared access method is a SAS token which is then given to

```
blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name='ocr-images',blob_name=blob.name, sas_token=sas)
```

for generating url for each image

The URL generated when passed to Azure ocr api, shows error

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation=false

But when url is generated manually from azure portal, it works perfectly. Can some one help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you're using the method `generate_blob_shared_access_signature` incorrectly.

There are a number of issues with the values you're passing to this method.

For `permission`, you need to provide one of the possible values of [`BlobPermissions`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.models.html#azure.storage.blob.models.BlobPermissions). Assuming you would want to read the blob contents, I would recommend that you use `BlobPermissions.READ` permission.

Both of your start and expiry dates are in the past. Furthermore, you just need to specify the date value and not include `st=` and `se=`.

Please try with the following code:

```
generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name='ocr-images',blob_name=blob.name,permission=BlobPermissions.READ,expiry='2019-04-09',start='2019-04-08')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I used the code as per you mentioned above and now I cannot access the blob. When I open the generated url in browser, it shows 404 error

Comment: Please share the SAS URL you’re using.

Comment: sas token: st=2019-04-09&se=2019-04-10&sp=r&sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=TgkeUIHuv3uiFppMMpByJQahwwPugem6J8SZ/Z2Iv7M%3D and sas url: https://externalimages.blob.core.windows.net/ocr-images/masked_image0.png?st=2019-04-09&se=2019-04-10&sp=r&sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=TgkeUIHuv3uiFppMMpByJQahwwPugem6J8SZ/Z2Iv7M%3D

Comment: Please make sure that blob container `ocr-images` exist in your storage account. When I tried to access the URL, I get the message saying `The specified container does not exist`.

Comment: I found the answer. I had to create an object of BlobSharedAccessSignature() and  use generate_blob() method for the sas token. sas token was not created with permissions so the image was not loading. any how it is done. Thank you for helping me

Comment: Awesome! Please post your solution as an answer. It might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In case of 404 error while creating url from SAS token blob it is required to create a SAS token from BlobSharedAccesssignature.

Here is my code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob.models import BlobPermissions
from azure.storage.blob.sharedaccesssignature import BlobSharedAccessSignature

account_name = data_dict['blob_storage_account_name']
account_key = data_dict['blob_storage_account_key']
top_level_container_name = data_dict['blob_container_name']
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)
blob_shared = BlobSharedAccessSignature(account_name, account_key)
```

Once you have object from BlobSharedAccessSignature, call generate_blob method which create sas token for individual blob from your container

```
sas = blob_shared.generate_blob(container_name=top_level_container_name, blob_name=blob.name,
                                     permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry='2019-04-10',
                                     start='2019-04-09')   

sas_url= 'https://'+account_name+'.blob.core.windows.net'+'/'+top_level_container_name+'/'+blob.name+'?'+sas
```